# Obtaining a new basis for a lattice with one of the new basis vectors fixed

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrix-equations, integer-lattices

Suppose that a lattice $L$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is given with a basis $B = \mathbf{ \{ v_1, v_2, v_3 \} }$. Is there an algorithm that would help me obtain a new basis $B' = \mathbf{ \{ v_1', v_2', v_3' \} }$ for the same lattice $L$ such that $\mathbf{v_1'}$ is constrained to be along a certain lattice direction (smallest vector along the direction $\mathbf{v_1}'$).

I would also like to mention that this is not a homework problem and I am a researcher in engineering. It is possible that a solution already exists but I am not aware of all the terminology in the field of lattice problems. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Edit: After Simon's answer, I would like to edit the question such that the volume occupied by the parallelepiped formed by the vectors of the basis $\mathbf{B'}$ to be the smallest possible volume in lattice $L$.

For example, one might consider $\mathbb{Z}^3$ with $\mathbf{v_1}=[1,0,0]^T$, $\mathbf{v_2}=[0,1,0]^T$ and $\mathbf{v_3}=[0,0,1]^T$ forming the basis $B$. This has volume 1 and while other bases are possible, one cannot find a basis of volume less than 1. Now the new basis $\mathbf{B'}$ should also have the same volume=1 in $\mathbb{Z}^3$.

Comment: When you say $\mathbf{v}_1'$ is constrained to be along a certain lattice vector, do you mean that it is fixed up to a choice of length? If not, then choosing $(2,0)$ as one vector for $\mathbb{Z}^2\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ means we can not extend this to a basis, as we need the product of the lengths of the basis vectors to be equal to $1$ (the covolume of the lattice).

Comment: No, just the direction is constrained. The length can be picked to be the shortest along that direction. I am assuming that a new basis can be described for any direction as long as it is a part of the lattice. In your example, we will chose $\mathbf{v_1'}$ to be (1,0).

Comment: In that case, you want to find a unimodular matrix with the vector $(a_1,a_2,a_3)^T$ as the first column, such that $\mathbf{v}_1'=a_1\mathbf{v}_1+a_2\mathbf{v}_2+a_3\mathbf{v}_3$. The other columns of the matrix will give you the other basis vectors.

Comment: Dear Daniel, would you mind elaborating what you mean by "find a unimodular matrix". I know that $(a_1, a_2, a_3)^T$ can be easily obtained by $B^{-1}\mathbf{v_1'}$ (basis vectors are assumed to be column vectors here). This forms the first column of the unimodular matrix. How are the other two columns obtained. If it is a routine problem in the algebra community, I would really appreciate it if you could provide me with some resources that I can read up. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that there are infinitely many possible solutions, even in a particularly basic case: Consider if you have constrained not just $\vec{v_1} = (1,0,0)^T$, but also $\vec{v_2} = (0,1,0)^T$. Then you could pick $\vec{v_3}$ to be any vector of the form $(0,n,1)^T$ for any integer $n$ (or even more generally, any of the form $(m,n,1)^T$). So even if you have constrained the first two, there are infinitely many possibilities for the third.

Comment: Simon, Thank you for this example and you are absolutely right. I was definitely aware that there would be many answers but I did not quite think of them being infinite. This is a very good example and now I get this feeling that there are infinitely many possible solutions for all cases. At least for the problem that I have in hand, I am interested in the basis with the smallest volume. There might still be multiple solutions but it won't be infinite. I will edit the question accordingly. I wonder how to arrive at the solutions in this case! Thank you.

Comment: Actually, any such basis (no matter the $m, n$) will have volume 1! This is since the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by the basis vectors has volume given by the determinant of the matrix. For $\vec{v_i}$ to be a basis, this must have determinant 1. So any new basis will be from a parallelepiped of volume 1.

Comment: That is true, Simon. I should have carefully checked it. Hmm... I guess my question is not well formulated yet. Thank you for your help.